# How to put most recent item for Changelog at the top in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, changelog

The code I use for this makes a changelog which tracks every change made in a different sheet and puts them in a nice format in a seperate changelog sheet.

The only problem I have with this is that the recent changes get put at the bottom, u can imagine that after 600 edits I would have to scroll quite a bit to get to the recent changes.

How do I make this work?

Code:

```js
function myFunction1(e) {  
  var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentSheetName = currentSheet.getName();
  var previousValue = e.oldValue;
  var newValue = cell.getValue();
  var typeChange = "Edit";
 
  
  // if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change to avoid recursion
  if (currentSheetName == changelogSheetName) return;
  var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  
  if (changelogSheet == null) {
   
    // no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
    changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
    
    Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
    
    ss.setActiveSheet(currentSheet);    
    changelogSheet.getRange('A1:G1').setBackground('#E0E0E0');
    changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet", "Cell", "Type", "Old Value", "New Value", "User"]);
    changelogSheet.deleteColumns(8,19);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 170);
    changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(7, 170); 
    changelogSheet.protect();
  }
  
 
  var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  
  if (previousValue == null){
    typeChange = "Add"; 
  } else if (newValue == "") {
    typeChange = "Remove";  
  } 
  
  changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, currentSheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), typeChange, previousValue, newValue, user]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, currentSheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), typeChange, previousValue, newValue, user]);
```

with this:

```
var new_row = [timestamp, currentSheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), typeChange, previousValue, newValue, user];
changelogSheet.insertRowBefore(2).getRange(2,new_row.length).setValues(new_row);
```

or (if there will be troubles):

```
var new_row = [timestamp, currentSheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), typeChange, previousValue, newValue, user];
changelogSheet.insertRowBefore(2);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
changelogSheet.getRange(2,new_row.length).setValues(new_row);
```

And I'd use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` instead of `Utilities.sleep(2000)`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion and I've tried both of them but it first gives me the error of

TypeError: Cannot read property 'oldValue' of undefined

Which probably is because there is no oldValue yet but I still get the error and I think it's messing up some things in my script so how do I fix this before being able to check if your solution worked?

Comment: "_The code I use for this makes a changelog_". I though this is the code. If not, please, post _the code_. If you mean to fix the code in OP -- try to rename the function into `onEdit(e)`. And don't try to run it from Script Editor. `onEdit()` fires automatically every time you edit your sheet manually. But I'm afraid this implementation will be too slow.